# viewWillAppear method is not calling iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

navigated from one view to another will and when i pop my view back viewWillAppear method is not calling.

can you please let me know the reason.

Comment: We will need some more information, like how does the view get presented.

Comment: Views themselves don't have that feature, only viewcontrollers do that. So this is not called when you do addSubview/removeFromeSuperview. If you're pushing/popping viewcontrollers, you need to show how you're doing that.

Comment: i am pushing from one viewcontroller to another view controller

Answer (score 0):

When you load View the first time viewWillAppear method is called? try to use

> [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

to return back

Answer (score 0):

If u are doing all well than ur application is crashed some where, use break point and check , even you can check and follow these steps......

step 1. for push in `FirstViewController`

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]init]
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:TRUE];
```

Step 2. for pop in `SecondViewController`

//check navigation controller exist in ur application stack

```
NSArray *arrView = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

NSLog(@"arrView %@",arrView);

for(int i = 0; i <[arrView count]-1, i++)
{
    if([arrView objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class])
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's typical that these problems are caused by improper use of view controller containment. You need to look at your view controller hierarchy and research the following methods:

```
[UIViewController addChildViewController:];
[UIViewController removeFromParentViewController:];
[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]
[UIViewController willMoveToParentViewController:]
[UIViewController didMoveToParentViewController:]
```

Read the **Implementing a Container View Controller** section of the [UIViewController Class Reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score -1):

I've also met this situation.
In iOS 5, it's ok.
But when I test in iOS 4.3.1, viewWillAppear is not calling.

So you need call viewWillAppear manually

You can try this

```
[[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: here our problem is we have so many navigations from 2 view controllers, as you said we need to call this in our back button handler....if we do that for very back that ill execute and we don't want that, we want to call that method only for the last back button handler

Comment: You shouldn't call `viewWillAppear:` manually; there is a deeper problem that should be found and addressed.